# Is weighted Kappa calculated by `irr` package in R wrong?

Tags: python, r, scikit-learn, irr, kappa

I found the `irr` package has 2 big bugs for the calculation of `weighted kappa`.

**Please tell me if the 2 bugs are really there or I misunderstood someting.**

You can replicate the bugs using the following examples.

**First bug: The sort of labels in confusion matrix needs to be corrected.**

I have 2 pairs of scores for disease extent (from 0 to 100 while 0 is healthy, 100 is extremely ill).

In `label_test.csv` (you can just copy and paste the data to your disk to do the following test):

```
0
1
1
1
0
14
53
3
```

In `pred_test.csv`:

```
0
1
1
0
3
4
54
6
```

in `script_r.R`:

```
library(irr)
label <- read.csv('label_test.csv',header=FALSE)
pred <- read.csv('pred_test.csv',header=FALSE)

kapp <- kappa2(data.frame(label,pred),"unweighted")
kappa <- getElement(kapp,"value")
print(kappa)  # output: 0.245283

w_kapp <- kappa2(data.frame(label,pred),"equal")
weighted_kappa <- getElement(w_kapp,"value")
print(weighted_kappa)  # output: 0.443038
```

When I use `Python` to calculate the `kappa` and `weighted_kappa`, in `script_python.py`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import cohen_kappa_score

label = pd.read_csv(label_file, header=None).to_numpy()
pred = pd.read_csv(pred_file, header=None).to_numpy()
kappa = cohen_kappa_score(label.astype(int), pred.astype(int))
print(kappa)  # output: 0.24528301886792447
weighted_kappa = cohen_kappa_score(label.astype(int), pred.astype(int), weights='linear', labels=np.array(list(range(100))) )
print(weighted_kappa)  # output: 0.8359908883826879
```

We can find that the `kappa` calculated by `R` and `Python` is the same, but the `weighted_kappa` from `R` is far lower than the `weighted_kappa` in `sklearn` from `Python`. Which is wrong? After 2-day research, I found that the `weighted_kappa` from `irr` package in `R` is wrong. Details are as follows.

During the debuging, we will find the confusion matrix in `irr` from `R` is:

[image]

We can find that the order is wrong. The order of labels should be changed from `[0, 1, 14, 3, 4, 53, 54, 6]` to `[0, 1, 3, 4, 6, 14, 53, 54]` as it is in Python. It seems that `irr` package used a string-based sort method instead of integer-based sort method, which will put `14` to the front of `3`. This mistake could be and should be corrected easily.

**Second bug: The confusion matrix is not complete in R**

In my `pred_test.csv` and `label_test.csv`, the values can not cover all possible values from 0 to 100. So the default confusion matrix in `irr` from `R` will miss those values which does not appear in data. This should be fixed.

Let's see another example.

In `pred_test.csv`, let's change the label from `54` to `99`. Then, we run `script_r.R` and `script_python.py` again. The results are:

```
In R:
kappa: 0.245283
weighted_kappa: 0.443038

In Python:
kappa: 0.24528301886792447
weighted_kappa: 0.592891760904685
```

We can find the `weighted_kappa` from `irr` in `R` is unchanged at all. But the `weighted_kappa` from `sklearn` in `Python` is decreased from `0.83` to `0.59`. So we know `irr` made a mistake again.

The reason is that `sklearn` can let us to pass the `full labels` to the confusion matrix so that the confusion matrix shape will be 100 * 100, however in `irr`, the labels of confusion matrix is calculated from the unique values from `label` and `pred`, which will miss a lot of other possible values. This mistake will assign the same weight to `53` and `99` here. So it is better to provide an option in `irr` package to let custumer provide the custum `labels` like what they have done in `sklearn` from `Python`.

Comment: You may want to contact the creator(s) of the package to pick this up with them.

Answer (score 1):

The solution from the authors is not going to work because in the [code](https://github.com/cran/irr/blob/master/R/kappa2.R) of kappa2 function, it converts your ratings into a matrix, and once you convert a factor into matrix, the levels are lost, this is the line:

```
ratings <- as.matrix(na.omit(ratings))
```

You can try it on your data, it is converted into a character:

```
lvl = 0:100
ratings = data.frame(label = factor(label[,1],levels=lvl),
                     pred = factor(pred[,1],levels=lvl))

 as.matrix(ratings)
     label pred
[1,] "0"   "0" 
[2,] "1"   "1" 
[3,] "1"   "1" 
[4,] "1"   "0" 
[5,] "0"   "3" 
[6,] "14"  "4" 
[7,] "53"  "54"
[8,] "3"   "6"
```

Same results:

```
kappa2(ratings,weight="equal")
 Cohen's Kappa for 2 Raters (Weights: equal)

 Subjects = 8 
   Raters = 2 
    Kappa = 0.368 

        z = 1.79 
  p-value = 0.0742
```

I suggest using `DescTools`, you just need to provide the confusion matrix using `table()` function in R, with the factors declared correctly as above:

```
library(DescTools)

CohenKappa(table(ratings$label,ratings$pred), weight="Unweighted")
[1] 0.245283

CohenKappa(table(ratings$label,ratings$pred), weight="Equal-Spacing")
[1] 0.8359909
```

Answer (score 0):

I have sent email to the author of the package, and he said he will fix the bug in next update.

Details are as follows:

> Actually, I am aware of this awkward behavior of the kappa2-function.
> This is due to the conversion and reordering of factor levels. These
> are actually not two bugs but only one that results in an incorrect
> generation of the confusion matrix (which you already found out). You
> can easily fix it by deleting the first row in the kappa2-function
> ("ratings <- as.matrix(na.omit(ratings))"). This conversion to
> numerical value as part of the removal of NA ratings is responsible
> for the error.
>
> In general, my function needs to know the factor levels in order to
> correctly compute kappa. Thus, for your data, you would need to store
> the values as factors with the appropriate possible factor levels.
> E.g.
>
> label <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 14, 53, 3) label <- factor(label,
> levels=0:100) pred <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 3, 4, 54, 6) pred <- factor(pred,
> levels=0:100)
>
> ratings <- data.frame(label,pred)
>
> When you now run the modified kappa2-function (i.e. without the first
> line), the results should be correct.
>
> kappa2(ratings) # unweighted kappa2(ratings, "equal") # weighted kappa
> with equal weights
>
> For the next update of my package, I will take this into account.